# Button is not working yet there is no error shown

Tags: android, kotlin

I just started learning kotlin and I am following a tutorial from 5 months ago. I figured that I have to use jetpack view binding as kotline synthetics is no longer supported. However, after looking on the forum for answers and following the suggested methods my button doesn't seem to work despite adding all the new codes.

This is my MainActivity

```
package com.example.findmyage

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.findmyage.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.Calendar

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        binding.buGetAge.setOnClickListener {
            val userDOB = Integer.parseInt(binding.edDOB.text.toString())
            val currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val userAge = currentYear - userDOB
            binding.teYourAge.text = "Your Age is $userAge Years Old"
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00BCD4"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edDOB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your DOB"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teYourAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
        android:shadowColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:text="Your Age"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_on_secondary"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edDOB" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buGetAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:text="Get your Age"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/design_default_color_background"
        android:textColorLink="#FFEB3B"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/teYourAge"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using binding but you are using a normal set view. setContentView(R.layout.activity_main).

So that button click not working.

Use below two lines

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

With viewBinding you can not use setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

You have to use  setContentView(binding?.root) instand of setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)